# React-yandex-maps Как сделать что бы функция loadSuggest выполнялось при onChange?

Tags: reactjs, яндекс-карты

```
const loadSuggest = ymaps => {
    const suggestView = new ymaps.SuggestView("suggest");
    console.log(suggestView)
  };

<YMaps>
        <Map
          onLoad={ymaps => loadSuggest(ymaps)}
          defaultState={{ center: [55.751574, 37.573856], zoom: 9 }}
          modules={["SuggestView"]}
        />
        <input type="text" id='suggest' />
      </YMaps>
```

console.log(suggestView) выполняется лишь при загрузке что не удивительно ибо стоит события onLoad. Но как добавить события при изменений. Либо к примеру при focusOut. Мне требуется получить адресс что написал пользователь + дополнительные данные что возвращает **suggestView**
Спасибо